# Restore AccessToken from my server Facebook Android SDK 4.0

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, facebook-sdk-4.x

Working with facebook sdk > 4.0 i'v got a problem, that i save my AccessToken but i don't get how to retrieve it or to check for availability? Facebook doc says to use `Session.open(AccessToken, StatusCallback)` sdk 4.0  but `Session` class is deprecated and was removed. How can i create an AccessToken from previously saved params ?

Comment: AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() or something like that. Check that class.

Comment: I have saved my params into shared preferences, is it possible to restore them ??

Comment: If you use SharedPreference, then you must know how to retrieve saved values from SP